# Zip without compression (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, zip, tar

I am using the **TZipFile** class provided natively by Delphi and I am wondering **if it is possible to pack / unpack without compression**, similar to the tar command in unix.In this case, we seek the greatest efficiency in extracting and writing files into a package.
Thanks.

Comment: Documentation for `System.Zip.TZipCompression` shows the available options. Did you look at those? `zcStored`seems to be the one you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks Tom, you're right, I had looked at the initial properties without finding such an option, but I hadn't looked in this class, where there are different options for handling the type of compression.

Comment: It is the type of the `Compression` parameter in most overloads of procedure `TZipFile.Add(const FileName: string; const ArchiveFileName: string = ''; Compression: TZipCompression = zcDeflate); overload;

Comment: Exactly Tom, I'm enclosing the code with the answer, for some absent-minded person to get here too. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:** zip-without-compression-delphi

The key is to use the **ZcStored** option in the TZipFile.Add procedure.

Attached is a working example that answers my question, in case anyone falls into the same issue that has been kindly resolved by **Tom Brunberg**

// Uses system.zip;

```
Procedure MakeZipFile;
Var
 fZip: TzipFile;
 PathZip, MyPathFile: String;
begin
 fZip := TZipFile.Create;
 Try
   PathZip := 'C:\example.zip';
   MyPathFile := 'C:\myfile.txt';
   fZip.Open(PathZip, zmWrite);
   fZip.Add(MyPathFile, '', ZcStored); // Thanks Tom
   fZip.Close;
 Finally
   fZip.Free; 
 end;
end;
```

[image: Compression type Tzipfile Delphi]